# How to get SelectionStart and SelectionLength from RTF-Section

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

I am trying to get my head around this:

I need to be able to find the selected part of a rtf text in its representation. I think I might be able to do this by iterating char by char for the text representation and looking at `SelectedRtf` over and over again, checking if it was in my initial section, until I found all of it and return. But to me this seems overkill for such a seemingly simple thing to do.

To find headings in my texts, I created this expression to find underlined headings:

```
\\ul (\b[^\s]+\b):\\ul
```

This match gives me the word of the heading (assuming it is underlined and followed up by a `:`).
This pattern is used in text analyzing methods in my program and works fine for rtf:

```
\par
\ul Headline:\ulnone\par
\par
```

> In the above text, the RegEx finds me the name of the heading. (https://regex101.com/r/UYr8em/1)

So far I have tried to obtain the indices like this:

```
private (int selectionStart, int selectionEnd) TranslateIndices(int rtfSelectionStart, int rtfSelectionEnd)
    {
        using(RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox())
        {
            string rtfSection = richTextBox1.Rtf.Substring(rtfSelectionStart, rtfSelectionEnd - rtfSelectionStart);
            rtb.SelectedRtf = rtfSection;

            int start = rtb.SelectionStart;
            int end = rtb.SelectionStart + rtb.SelectionLength;

            return (start, end);
        }
    }
```

As I expected, `rtfSection` is not a valid rtf text and the line `rtb.SelectedRtf = rtfSection;` throws an exception. So now I am at the start and might need someone to guide me in the right direction.

Another thing I noted is, that of course the `SelectedRtf` I am setting is out of context, with no other rtf text in the `RichTextBox`. (No header, e.g.)

So when I use the index of the `Match` object, it doesn't work with the normal text, but with the rtf text it matched on. Of couse that makes sense. But how am I able to convert an index in the rtf text, to an index in its representation?

Comment: Welcome Mr X ! upvoted your question.. there are some interesting topics on SO about RTF parsing you may want to check out. Search option https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+rtf+parsing

Comment: @Goodies I am looking into this. I'll post the answer to my problem if I find it there. Beside from my problem it contains some good information for possible future problems.